# Can't access ttyACM device in mode 0660

Tags: usb, fedora, udev, usbserial

I want to be able to read and write ttyACM device, particularly Arduino Leonardo board under Fedora.

I made a following rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8036", SYMLINK+="arduino", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Symlink is created but I do not have permission to read the device:

```
[nexy@shire ~]$ cat /dev/arduino 
cat: /dev/arduino: Permission denied
```

Showing ls gives the following:

```
[nexy@shire ~]$ ls -l /dev/arduino /dev/ttyACM0 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root         7 Dec 18 15:25 /dev/arduino -> ttyACM0
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 166, 0 Dec 18 15:25 /dev/ttyACM0
```

When I change mode to 0666 then it works. I belong to the group plugdev:

```
[nexy@shire ~]$ sudo groups nexy
nexy : nexy wheel plugdev
```

Comment: Can you just run `groups` and `ls -l /dev/arduino /dev/ttyACM*` and post the output here?  Also, what port are you trying to access, how are you trying to access it, and what error message do you get when accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to log out and log back in or restart your computer if you just added yourself to the group recently.

Comment: No, I am in this group since I installed my system and also my other devices work.